# Bash script that automatically moves files into directory with the name of the file

Tags: bash

## Problem:

I need a bash script that makes a directory that automatically uses the webm files name as the directory name. Move the webm file into the directory of the webm files name. Move all files with the webm files name into the directory sharing the webm files name.

## Example files:

28y95.webm 28y95.description 28y95.info.json

n7isk.webm n7isk.description n7isk.info.json

f89af.webm f89af.description f89af.info.json

## What I want:

The 28y95 directory:

28y95.webm 28y95.description 28y95.info.json

The n7isk directory:

n7isk.webm n7isk.description n7isk.info.json

The f89af directory:

f89af.webm f89af.description f89af.info.json

I tried this and it only worked for webm. It did not work for .info.json and .description files.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Works, WEBM

set -o errexit -o nounset

for file in *.webm
do
    dir="${file%.webm}"
    mkdir -- "$dir"
    mv -- "$file" "$dir"
done

#

set -o errexit -o nounset

for file in *.json
do
    dir="${file%.json}"
    mkdir -- "$dir"
    mv -- "$file" "$dir"
done

#

set -o errexit -o nounset

for file in *.description
do
    dir="${file%.description}"
    mkdir -- "$dir"
    mv -- "$file" "$dir"
done

#
```

This is what happens when I run this.

```
chmod +x run.sh
./run.sh

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘\*’: File exists
```

Comment: `mkdir` is exiting with 1 when attempting to create a directory that already exists, so when you have `set -o errexit` your script will exit on this error condition.  You can alter your script to check if the directory exists prior to creating or remove the `set -o errexit`.

Comment: consider `mkdir -p -- "$dir"` to silently ignore 'directory exists' error

Comment: `file=28y95.info.json` ... `${file%.json}` => `28y95.info`; I'm assuming you don't really want to create a directory named `*.info`

Comment: why 3 separate loops instead of just copying all matching files in the first loop, eg, `mv -- "${dir}".* "${dir}"`

Comment: Don't post answers in questions. Post an answer, then the Stack algorithm can treat the q&a correctly.

Comment: If you solved your own question, put the solution in the "Your Answer" box below. After a day or so you can accept your own answer. Do not put answers in questions, or put "Solved!" in your title, neither of those things mark your question as answered in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help! I'll show what worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset

for file in *.webm
do
    dir="${file%.webm}"
    mkdir -p -- "$dir"
    mv -- "${dir}".* "${dir}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer to your question! Don't hesitate to mark your answer as accepted: this helps in maintaining high quality over here on Stackoverflow :)